# screen just opens for a second and disappears

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I just tried a code to draw a star in turtle graphics, the code works in vs code but the screen just opens for a second and disappeared

```
import turtle
a = turtle. Turtle()
a.getscreen().bgcolor("black")

a.penup()
a.goto(-200, 100)
a.pendown()
a.color("yellow")
a.speed(25)

def star(turtle, size):
    if size <= 10:
        return
    else:
        turtle.begin_fill()
        for i in range(5):
            turtle.forward(size)
            star(turtle, size/3)
            turtle.left(216)
        turtle.end_fill()

star(a, 360)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: As written, your code has some syntax issues. Please [edit] with the properly formatted code

Comment: "but the screen just opens for a second and disappeared" In your own words, why should anything else happen? What do you think `turtle.done()` means? After that happens, is there any more for your program to do? If not, then why should it stay open?

Comment: Whatever you said that's correct karl but the main issue is that the screen starts after I run the code but without even starting to draw the star the screen closes within a second so this is the issue, kindly help me out

Comment: Raj: It's important to post properly formatted code so other people can copy and run it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Do *you* know what [`turtle.done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop) means/does?

Answer (score 0):

As edited by @OneCricketeer, @Jay and @JanWilamowski, your code runs great on my system and makes a cool image.

Yes, there are issues with the code, like the out of range argument to `speed()` but it knows how to cope regardless.  I would have written this code slightly differently:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def star(turtle, size):
    if size <= 10:
        return

    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(size)
        star(turtle, size/3)
        turtle.left(216)

    turtle.end_fill()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color('yellow')
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-200, 100)
turtle.pendown()

star(turtle, 360)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.mainloop()
```

See if that helps with your screen disappearance issue or not.  If not, you might have to look outside your program for the cause.